# Tornado HTTPServer is blocking a continuous async callback

Tags: python, asynchronous, websocket, tornado, httpserver

I'm working on a problem for quite some time now.

What I want is a Tornado Server that can receive filenames via websockets from multiple sources. The filenames will just be stored in a global queue. Now, what I want is a service that works continuously in the background with the names in the queue. Here is what I tried:

```python
class MainLoop:
    inst: IOLoop
    queue: AudioQueue

class WSHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    def on_message(self, msg):
        log("Receiving the name of a ready file")
        MainLoop.queue.put_nowait(msg)
        self.write_message("file name received")

async def check_queue(executor, loop):
    while True:
        log(f"Checking queue: {MainLoop.queue.qsize()}")
        if MainLoop.queue.not_empty:
            await loop.run_in_executor(executor, MainLoop.queue.convert_oldest)
        await sleep(1)

def main():
    _executor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(10)

    application = tornado.web.Application([(r"/ws-audio", WSHandler)])
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(application)
    http_server.listen(PORT)
    log(f"Server running on port {PORT}")

    MainLoop.queue = AudioQueue()
    MainLoop.inst = IOLoop.current()
    MainLoop.inst.add_callback(check_queue, _executor, MainLoop.inst)
    MainLoop.inst.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Very stripped down, but that's the gist of it. Now looking at the logs I get that the server runs on the specified port and one time that the queue is being checked. But by my understanding and according to this [article](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-perform-multitasking-in-flask-and-tornado-3f00945f4510) the queue should be checked every second. So something must be blocked by the Server. If I actually send over a filename it will be put in the queue and afterwards the queue will indeed be checked and the file processed. But only once which isn't enough if a connection sends many files at the same time.

I'm at my wits end here and think there is something very obvious that I don't understand about websockets and io loops yet. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The code that you've posted above should work as you expect. However, I'm not sure about this function: `MainLoop.queue.convert_oldest`. This appears the only function that could potentially stop your `while-loop` at the `await` statement. Can you remove this and maybe try with a different, dummy function (something like `lambda: None`) to check if the queue is being checked every second or not.

Comment: @xyres That actually was the problem. Seems like `if MainLoop.queue.not_empty:` did not do what I think it did. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Nice. Consider adding an answer to your question and mark it solved.